# google-libphonenumber package does not validate chinese phone number in local format

Tags: internationalization, phone-number, libphonenumber

The follow Chinese phone number is how you would dial domestically in China: **021 68336892**
Internationally: **+86 2168336892**

The following code is to validate a Chinese phone number using google-libphonenumber

```
const phoneUtil = require("google-libphonenumber").PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
//+86 2168336892 //isValid
//021 68336892 //INVALID
const number = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput("021 68336892", "CH");

const isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(number);
console.dir(isValid);
```

Only the international number passes validation. Is there a way with google-libphonenumber to have both pass validation?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late to be helpful for you now, but "CH" is not the country code for China.  Try using "CN".